# Get the repeating records from table only once?

Tags: php, mysql

I know this question has been asked more than thousand's times and i tried thousand of the hint's  but still no success. I have applied the DISTINCT ,group by and many more and now i need your helps.[image: This is my table structure]

I need to do .if the table  field `to` or `from` is equal to session_id then retrieve the records from table,i want to retrieve the records only once, if there is a `from` whose value is  6 then retrieve it and don't retrieve another `form` or `to` column whose id value 6.

```
  select table.id, table.from, table.to, table.message, table.sent, table.read, table.direction from table where ((table.to ='82') or (table.from = '"82' ))  order by table.id DESC
```

I tried the DISTINCT and group by but no success.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT table.id, table.from, table.to, table.message, table.sent, table.read, table.direction FROM table WHERE ( ( table.to = '82' ) OR ( table.from = '82' ) ) GROUP BY table.from, table.to ORDER BY table.id DESC LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you paste your query with group by which you have tried?

Comment: I don't understand. To me the sample data you have listed has no duplicates, each ID is distinct and each message has different content.  So what expected results are you looking for?

Comment: @Niranjan SELECT DISTINCT table.id, table.from, table.to, table.message, table.sent, table.read, table.direction
FROM table
WHERE (
(
table.to =  '82'
)
OR (
table.from =  '82'
)
)
GROUP BY table.from, table.to
ORDER BY table.id DESC 
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: paste that in your question ^

Comment: What are the features of the only record you want to retrieve for each session_id? Just one, nevermind which it is?

Comment: `'82'` you're checking for a string. If `from` and `to` are an `int` type, then it will fail. If it is int, remove the quotes. Check for errors on the query.

Comment: "and don't retrieve another form or to column whose id value 6" - "limit 1" or what do you want?

Comment: @Mohit, try grouping by table.id once

Comment: @Simimmo My main idea is to arrange the latest message's. one message for each user this looks simple but complete headache for me from last 5 hours.

Comment: so... `from` and `to` are what type? You didn't answer me yet about this. Plus, brackets are for subqueries https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/subqueries.html which you do not have.

Comment: The query is running with no error,s. they are of int types

Comment: whatever. Ok well, good luck. I hope you get what you're looking for. I am moving on. cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- The from and to are of int type.  now the from has an id suppose six which is repeating six times in from and 6 times in to with different time slices . Now i want to get this id 6 only once. and same for the other rest id's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should first find the more recent message for each couple:

```
    SELECT table.id, table.from, table.to, table.message, table.sent, table.read, table.direction 
    FROM table
    WHERE table.id IN
    ( select max(table.id)
        from table 
    group by table.to, table.from 
    )
```

Comment: Only one message for each user's , suppose 50 user have conversation to me then how will i get the rest 49

Answer (score -1):

You can get 1(Last) record by adding LIMIT 1 at end of your query.

```
select table.id, table.from, table.to, table.message, table.sent, table.read, table.direction from table where ((table.to ='82') or (table.from = '"82' ))  LIMIT 1
```

Comment: I know the limit works for me but i have to retrieve thousand's of records not only one.

Comment: I am assuming 82 is User ID. If you want to retrieve thousand of records. Then why you use table.to ='82' to fetch record of 82 Only ???